# GridDB puts data have not success

Tags: griddb

When I puts data on GridDB_NoSQL sever : 
 
Data includes : 1000 row && 10000 column (String data 20 byte) 
 I see notification:

```
[ 0 ]
60015

[60015:DS_DS_SCHEMA_INVALID] Number of columns = 10000 is invalid (address=10.116.41.212:10001, partition=97)
[ 1 ]
60015

[60015:DS_DS_SCHEMA_INVALID] Number of columns = 10000 is invalid
```

I can't puts data from client to sever. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the error is saying that you have too many columns.
I propose lowering your column count.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or asking the OP for more information? In case of the former: please [edit] the post to show *how* it solves the problem. In case of the latter, please delete this, as the "post answer" button is for answers only, see [answer]. Questions addressed to the OP should be put into comments.